# angular custom validation & firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, validation

I have tried to type costume validation dependent on lesson in web every think work great and validation return null or false but error message in html not changed

validation code is

```
export class customValidation{
  static duplicateEmail(afs:AngularFirestore){
    return (control:AbstractControl)=>{
      let email =  control.value;
      return afs.collection<any>(`users`, ref=>ref.where('email','==',email)).valueChanges()
                .pipe(
                  debounceTime(500),
                  take(1),
                  map(data => data.length ? {duplicateEmail:false} : null)
                ).subscribe(data=> {
                  console.log(data)
                  return data;
                })
    }
  }
}
```

form builder cod is

```
    this.signupForm = this.FB.group({
  email: ['', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.email,
    customValidation.duplicateEmail(this.afs)
  ]],
  password:['', [
    Validators.required
  ]]
})
```

and html code is

```
  {{signupForm.controls.email.invalid}}
<div *ngIf="email.invalid && email.dirty" class="danger-text">
    {{email.value}} is not available
  </div>
```

[image]

i have printed the result in console and its return null or false dependents on the email value but email.invalid stay true

Comment: You probably mean **custom** validation, don't you? :-)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec yes sorry for misspelling

Comment: Hello everyone any new idea